# Existence of limit

Tags: real-analysis

I am confused by sentences such as "the right hand limit exists but it could be infinite". Aren't non-existence and non-finiteness the same for real functions?

Comment: Do you know what it means when we say the limit exists?

Comment: Consider the difference between $f(x)=\log x$ and $g(y)=y+\sin y$.  I would say that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{y\to\infty}g(y)$ DNE.

Comment: You have lots of answers from other people.  But I would say that the phrase "limit" in the context of real numbers has a slightly ambiguous meaning.  When you first take a class in real variables, they mean that the limit has to be finite.  But it is also unambiguous what people mean when they say the limit of some quantity is infinite.  So I think when people write papers or books, they should be careful to state exactly what they mean by "limit."

Comment: If the limit is $\infty$ that means that the function increases indefinitely (or if it tends to $-\infty$ then it decreases forever). However, as the other people's examples have shown, it's possible for a limit to not exist and not be infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If a limit exists may depend whether we work on $\mathbb{R}$ or $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty,-\infty\}$. Rudin's *Real Analysis* assumes the later, which he calls the extended real-line.
2. Also notice that we can have bounded functions without limits: say $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=-1$ if $x$ is irrational, this function is discontinuous everywhere but it is bounded. So we can not assume non-existence is the same as non-finiteness.